# Writing objective -C client's console output to a file in the server

Tags: java, ios, server

I have a server written in java that listens on a specific port number. I also have an Objective-C client that connects to this server and communicates. The communication works fine. Now, I have to take the objective-c client's output from the terminal and put in in a file created by the java server. How do I go about doing this? Normal FileWriter functions doesnt seem to work. The below is a part of the server that I have.

```
// Get the client message
while((inputLine = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(inputLine);
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    //read a line from the console
    String lineFromInput = in.readLine();
    File file = new File("./user_statistics.txt");
    if(!file.exists()){
        file.createNewFile();
    }

    //create an print writer for writing to a file
    fileWriter  = new FileWriter(file);
    //output to the file a line
    fileWriter.write(lineFromInput);
}

//close the file 
fileWriter.close();  
serverSocket.close();
```

Comment: In what way does this not work? Do you get any error messages? Does it create an empty file or what?

Comment: It creates an empty file... It doesnt write anything to the file

Answer (score 0):

You start off by reading a line from the client (so far so good), but then you get input from the console and try to write that to the file instead. You should delete the console stuff and read from `inputLine` instead:

```
// Get the client message
while((inputLine = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(inputLine);

    //read a line from the console
    File file = new File("./user_statistics.txt");
    if(!file.exists()){
        file.createNewFile();
    }

    //create an print writer for writing to a file
    fileWriter  = new FileWriter(file);
    //output to the file a line
    fileWriter.write(inputLine);
}

//close the file 
fileWriter.close();  
serverSocket.close();
```

Incidentally: If you care about performance, you should use the `.read(char[] cbuf, int off, int len)` method of `bufferedReader`, instead of `.readLine()`. The way you've done it, it will waste time on:

- checking where the next line ending is;
- creating String objects (and eventually deleting them);
- possibly checking whether it needs to change character encoding, depending on your character encoding settings;
- using buffers well below the optimum size (I think a few KB is the norm).

Comment: Wow! Awesome... This works perfectly... I was scratching my head without knowing what the mistake was! Thanks!!!!!! It works like a charm now!